# Hiding Literal control declaratively in header (ASP.NET web forms)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I try to hide some Javascript code in header by just using declarations. The Visible property should be controlled by a setting in web.config (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]).

However, for some reason setting the Visible property like this has no effect - it is always true:

```html
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <asp:Literal ID="JSLiteral" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough" Visible='<%# false %>'>
   Some JS
  </asp:Literal>
</head>
```

It is probably linked to page life cycle in ASP.NET. It works when setting this property in Page_Load event, but that's not what I want as I need to insert this block to a lot of web applications, and I don't want to recompile all of them.

Any ideas how this could be accomplished with minimal effort in ASP.NET? I don't want to mess around with the JS code, which needs to be added in header - it is code of a third-party.

Thanks in advance and cheers,
Roger

Comment: Just for clarification. When setting Visible="false" it works (which should be clear).
The declaration above is just showing that it does not work dynamically like this. The idea was to replace the code between '<%# %>' e.g. by !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Head1.DataBind();
}
```

What you are using is a DataBinding expression. So `DataBind()` has to be called.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! However, it involves code-behind. Any idea how this could be achieved just declaratively?

When using <% if () { %> following exception is thrown:
"The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."